# Google Analytics : _setvar to new tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have been using the older version of analytics code and used the following to track different types of users

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxxx");
pageTracker._setVar('memberlevel-2');    pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

How do I use this with the new asynchronous code? Google Analytics forums is dead and i got no response :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading this for setting custom variable:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html

Sample code for to track page view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`_setVar` still works, but you should use `_setCustomVar` instead, as its more powerful.

Here's what your old code looks like using the async code:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setVar', 'memberlevel-2']); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

To use setCustomVar instead, you could do this:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'memberlevel', '2', 3]);// page-level scope (3), in slot #1
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: Be careful, as the scope of `_setVar` and `_setCustomVar` is different. By default, `_setVar` sets a persistent, user-level variable, suitable for setting a user's member level after login, for example. `_setCustomVar` defaults to page-level scope (3), which is better for tracking additional attributes of individual pages (categories, etc.). If you switch to `_setCustomVar`, you should specify 1 (user-level scope) for the fourth parameter. More info here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables